# bundle.min.js not getting updated in React Project

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to make a simple React-Redux Project. I imported a project from github and started making some tweaks in App.js. But when I try to run index.html file, bundle.min.js does not gets updates and shows the old results. I am not getting the way to update bundle.min.js file everytime I make any changes in my components. I am attaching snippets of my code.

index.html file

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>React Webpack</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="js/bundle.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react'
require('../../scss/style.scss');

const App =() =>(

    <div>
        <h2>
            Username list
        </h2>
        <hr/>
        <h2>
            User Details
        </h2>
    </div>
);

export default App;
```

reducer-user.js

```
export default function () {
    return [
        {
            id: 1,
            first: "Bucky",
            last: "Roberts",
            age: 71,
            description: "Bucky is a React developer and YouTuber",
            thumbnail: "http://i.imgur.com/7yUvePI.jpg"
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            first: "Joby",
            last: "Wasilenko",
            age: 27,
            description: "Joby loves the Packers, cheese, and turtles.",
            thumbnail: "http://i.imgur.com/52xRlm8.png"
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            first: "Madison",
            last: "Williams",
            age: 24,
            description: "Madi likes her dog but it is really annoying.",
            thumbnail: "http://i.imgur.com/4EMtxHB.png"
        }
    ]
}
```

[Project structure screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wi2aX.png)

[Browser Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bb4qa.png)

I should just get Two headings saying "Username list" and "User Details", but I am getting something completely different

Answer (score 0):

1. If you looking for making some tweaks in a quick working app just
   try this amazing tool
   https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2016/07/22/create-apps-with-no-configuration.html
2. Or if you wish to fix your problem (that seems to be a NodeJS
   project's dependencies issue) starting from opening a terminal and type

   ```
   cd yourProjectRootPathFolder
   npm init -y
   npm install --save-dev babel-core babel-cli babel-preset-es2015
   ```

   Then be sure to enable Babel's ES6/ES2015 language support, this it's
   done by activating the babel-preset-es2015 package that you already
   installed by the command above. Now you just need to add a "babel" section to package.json:

   ```
   "babel": {   "presets": ["es2015"] }
   ```

Comment: I solved it by installing webpack and then running the comment webpack. I have to do it every single time I change any code.